# How do I call notifyDatasetChanged on Tabbed Adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using OkHttpClient to populate 3 tabs with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter (I know, deprecated)-- which works, but when I change the data in another activity and return to the MainActivity the RecyclerView isn't updated, despite trying to call notifyDataSetChanged() everywhere I could think of. This question in various forms has been asked countless times, but none of the answers have gotten me anywhere.

My MainActivity is:

```
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private var InventoryItems: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = ArrayList()

    class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)

            callServer()
        }

        private fun callServer(){
            ...
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){
                    response.use {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
                        val resp = response.body!!.string()
                        this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                            parseJsonStr(resp)//loads InventoryItems array from Json response
                                //logging server response shows data in array is changed
                            setTabs()
                        })
                    }
                }
        }

        private fun setTabs(){
            pagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, InventoryItems, this@MainActivity)
            viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
            val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()//(...doesn't work here, or at the top of this function)
        }
    }
```

SectionsPagerAdapter is:

```
    private var InventoryTab1: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = ArrayList()//and same for Tab 2 and 3

    class SectionsPagerAdapter(
        fm: FragmentManager,
        private val invItems: MutableList<MutableList<String>>,
        private val context: Context
    ): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            ...//load tab arrays from invItems
            return when (position) {
                0 -> FirstFragment(InventoryTab1)
                1 -> SecondFragment(InventoryTab2)
                else -> ThirdFragment(InventoryTab3)
            }
        }
        override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
            return POSITION_NONE//tried this because of some SO answers
        }
    }
```

...and a Fragment is:

```
        private lateinit var rootView: View
        private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    class FirstFragment(private val items: MutableList<MutableList<String>>) : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
            recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bk_rv)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        fun clickListener(position: Int) {
            //intent to start other activity that changes server data
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val listener = { i: Int -> clickListener(i) }
        val inventoryAdapter = activity?.let { InventoryAdapter( items, it, listener ) }
        recyclerView.adapter = inventoryAdapter
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()//(...doesn't work here either)

        return rootView
    }
```

I've tried putting notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter in multiple locations, but to no avail. Logging the initial array shows that the data is changed in MainActivity, but this isn't passed to the Fragments.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this with

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

in my Fragment (lots of SO questions address this, good tutorial at [this link](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/getting-a-result-from-an-activity-android-startactivityforresult-example-kotlin/)); then

```
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra("index", rowNumStr)
    intent.putExtra("newValue", newValueStr)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
```

in the activity that submitted the change to the server; and back in the fragment:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val indexStr = data?.getStringExtra("index")
                val valueStr = data?.getStringExtra("newValue")
                items[indexStr!!.toInt()][5] = valueStr.toString()
                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!